# Barbell exercises to undo damage of sitting?

Tags: barbell

Apparently sitting for long periods leads to muscle imbalances. Due to my current situation, it is something I have to do. Hence I'd like to ask what would be some good barbell exercises to work against the negative effects of sitting?

Comment: Adding a hat imbalances  might help.

Comment: "Apparently sitting for long periods leads to muscle imbalances." No. Just stop listening to whoever told you this nonsense.

Comment: Overhead press and bent over rows.  However the idea that you can undo damage from sitting for a lot of hours every week by doing barbell exercises for a few minutes every week is probably both wrong and dangerous. As mentioned get up from your chair and move  as often as you can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Just exercise.

All the risks of a sedentary lifestyle can be mitigated by, well, not living a sedentary lifestyle. When we talk about deleterious health effects of sitting all day, we’re talking about people who sit all day, and do nothing else, for years. Just exercise regularly (a combination of resistance and aerobic training), and you’ve mitigated all the risk of a sedentary lifestyle simply by not having one.

Comment: Even getting up every hour, and walking a quick lap around your office, or the lower floor of your house, does a lot.

Answer (score 0):

do some squats, deadlifts and bent over rows to strengthen your core, lower back and legs which is weakened from sitting all day long/